# Embedded expressions are not replaced in the JSONPATH filter

Tags: karate

When i am passing the value of a string json filter is working fine. But when I am passing embedded expression in the JSONPATH it is not replacing actual value.

```
Given url appServer +'/integration/rest/user'+'?page=0'+'&pageSize=10'+'&fieldList=first_name,last_name,id,username,last_login,active,date_created'+'&filter=user_type%20equals%20%27P%27%20'+'&getTotalRecordCount=true'
```

And header X-CSRF-TOKEN = csrfToken
* cookie JSESSIONID = jsessionid
* print routevalue
* cookie route = routevalue
* string searchUser = 'anupama'

## * callonce sleep 10

## Given request ' '

When method get
Then status 200
* def usernames = get response.integration.serviceData.record[*].username
* print usernames
* print searchUser
* def userNode = get[0] response.integration.serviceData.record[?(@.username== '#(searchUser)')]
* print userNode[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embedded expressions are only for JSONPath and XML: https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions

Please use the `karate` API for dynamic JsonPath: https://github.com/intuit/karate#jsonpath-filters

```
* def userNode = karate.jsonPath(response, "$.integration.serviceData.record[?(@.username=='" + searchUser + "')]")
```